# ERROR: No matching distribution found for keras.saving.pickle_utils

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to attach a CNN trained model to a web page but I keep getting this error.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
model = pickle.load(open('model.pkl', 'rb'))
```

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement keras.saving.pickle_utils (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for keras.saving.pickle_utils
```

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling eras, tried downgrading tensorflow to version 2.9 but 2.12.0rc0 is the lowest it will go.

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.9.0 (from versions: 2.12.0rc0, 2.12.0rc1, 2.12.0, 2.12.1, 2.13.0rc0, 2.13.0rc1, 2.13.0rc2, 2.13.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.9.0
```

Now I'm running the code and I get this.

```
 File "/Volumes/Transcend/Masters/Semester 1/Data Analytics and ML/Assignments/Assignment 3/Web app/deploy-model-project/app.py", line 5, in <module>
    model = pickle.load(open('model.pkl', 'rb'))
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Volumes/Transcend/Masters/Semester 1/Data Analytics and ML/Assignments/Assignment 3/Web app/deploy-model-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/saving/pickle_utils.py", line 48, in deserialize_model_from_bytecode
    raise e
  File "/Volumes/Transcend/Masters/Semester 1/Data Analytics and ML/Assignments/Assignment 3/Web app/deploy-model-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/saving/pickle_utils.py", line 46, in deserialize_model_from_bytecode
    model = saving_lib.load_model(filepath, safe_mode=False)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Volumes/Transcend/Masters/Semester 1/Data Analytics and ML/Assignments/Assignment 3/Web app/deploy-model-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/saving/saving_lib.py", line 277, in load_model
    raise e
  File "/Volumes/Transcend/Masters/Semester 1/Data Analytics and ML/Assignments/Assignment 3/Web app/deploy-model-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/saving/saving_lib.py", line 229, in load_model
    ) as gfile_handle, zipfile.ZipFile(gfile_handle, "r") as zf:
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/zipfile.py", line 1299, in __init__
    self._RealGetContents()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/zipfile.py", line 1366, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

This is what I get when I try to launch the page now.

Comment: You posted an error dump, so I don't understand what you mean by "no apparent error"...

Comment: The error in the title is a pip error, no idea how this is related to the code. Seems you are trying random things, and that is not the way.